# How to exclude some class when parent class is selected

Tags: css

I'm sorry if this is a silliest question that you've ever found. I wanna find some "shortcut" to make this happen. Here's the example:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav></nav>
        <aside></aside>
        <footer></footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

I wanna give some style into the all of `.wrapper` content, except for the `footer`. Is it possible to handle it? Or... Is there any CSS selector for an exception?

NOTE: Please don't give me an "easy way" solution like this:

```
nav { 
    //some style
}
aside {
    //some same style
}
```

Comment: maybe this is what you want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Comment: Nope. `:not` selector can't be applied cause there's no same class/tag between each tag in my case

Comment: @nullexcptn - actually it can. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats quite easy. Just do it as follows:

```
.wrapper > *:not(footer)  {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: Sort of... But, how can i apply it into a bootstrap modal? i've tried `*:not(.modal)`, `*:not(.modal-dialog)`, but it still applied

Comment: You can omit the `*`.

Answer (score 2):

This may be helpful.

The `*` refers all elements and `*:not(footer)` says all elements except `footer` element.

This `.wrapper *:not(footer)` stands to select all elements except `footer` inside `.wrapper` class.

This is how it works.

```css
.wrapper *:not(footer)  {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav>01</nav>
        <aside>02</aside>
        <footer>03</footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It makes the process a little bit heavy. I think it's not a good solution for the client

Comment: You can omit the `*`.

Comment: It can be right. But it's better using `>` between `.wrapper` and `*not(footer)` due processing reason. Thanks a lot man!